# Values between two dates

Tags: python, django

I have a database in Django contains amounts and values stored by dates,
I want to calculate the values or the amounts between 2 dates 
how to do that ?

```
Date           the value
01/01/2018     500$
01/02/2018     700$
01/03/2018     800$
```

how to calculate the values from `01/01/2018` to `01/02/2018` for example ?

Comment: how to calculate the values from 01/01/2018 to 01/02/2018 for example ?

Comment: If those dates are strings, rather than `datetime`/`Timestamp` values, the first thing to do is convert them to `Timestamp` values. (Actually, the _first_ thing to do is specify them less ambiguously—is that 2 January or 1 February?) Then it's easy; it's the same question as "values between two numbers".

Answer (score 1):

First off, a queryset of value between the range data:

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(
                    Q(date__gte = date_start) & 
                    Q(date__lte = date_end)
            )
```

And then with Sum, you can have the sum of `value`

```
queryset.aggreage(total=Sum('value'))
```

Full code:

```
>>> from django.db.moedls import Q, Sum

>>> Model.objects.filter(
                    Q(date__gte = date_start) & 
                    Q(date__lte = date_end)
            ).aggreage(total=Sum('value'))

>>> {'total': 'a_number_here'}
```

> date_start, date_end should be `date` or `datetime` object